# how to filter records that including null values and other status

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am running below query in sql server. How to filter whose `checkpointstatus` is not 'Completed' including `null` values. But the issue is I am not able to get those records whose values are null.

```
  SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE CheckPointStatus != 'Completed'
```

I have tried to fix this by :

```
  SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE coalesce(CheckPointStatus, '') !=  'Completed'
```

But just want to make sure is this correct way?

Comment: How about  SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE ISNULL(CheckPointStatus,'NA') != 'Completed'

Comment: Or `SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE CheckPointStatus !=  'Completed' OR CheckPointStatus IS NULL`

Comment: your code should work perfectly!! Do you have an issue?

Comment: @AustinSchmidt if you do `CheckPointStatus IS NULL` i can't get other status records like processing, pending and all. I want to get other records aswell including null but those once which are other than completed including nulls

Comment: @user1030181 It's an `OR`, it will match all records that are not `Completed` _OR_ 'NULL'.

Comment: @AustinSchmidt You are right. Send me your answer to mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution:

```
SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE coalesce(CheckPointStatus, '') !=  'Completed'
```

works fine. Another solution that is more explicit, simple, and *possibly* cheaper would be

```
SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail 
    WHERE CheckPointStatus != 'Completed' OR CheckPointStatus IS NULL
```

which will match all records not equal to Completed or where the value is null.

Answer (score 5):

Try one of these methods:

**Method 1.**

```
SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE CheckPointStatus != 'Completed' 
                                 OR CheckPointStatus IS NULL
```

**Method 2.** (SQL Server 2008 and above) Using [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) function.

```
SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE ISNULL(CheckPointStatus,'') != 'Completed'
```

**Method 3.** (SQL Server 2008 and above) Using [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function.

```
SELECT * FROM TAMS.OrderDetail WHERE COALESCE(CheckPointStatus, '') !=  'Completed'
```

The third one, in fact is your own query, which is correct